# Creating a card deck in C++ with enums

Tags: c++, shuffle

I am working on practicing C++ to strengthen my skills. I want to build a deck of cards and filter them when a list of strings are passed in. The list would look something like this:

{"3c", "Js", "2d", "10h", "Kh", "8s", "Ac", "4h"}

and when filtered would return

{"2d", "8s", "Js", "3c", "Ac", "4h", "10h", "Kh"}

I have created a struct named card_t as so

```
struct card_t
{
    enum class rank_t: unsigned char
    {
        two = 2,
        three = 3,
        four = 4,
        five = 5,
        six = 6,
        seven = 7,
        eight = 8,
        nine = 9,
        ten = 10,
        jack = J,
        queen = Q,
        king = K,
        ace = A
        
        
    };
    
    enum class suit_t: unsigned char
    {
        h,
        d,
        c,
        s
    };
};
```

My compiler does not like the way rank_t is setup and I am not sure why. Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: I am an idiot. I am so use to Python inferring types. The letters are characters and need to be treated as such. So quotes are needed. Any other feedback would still be much appreciated

Comment: "My compiler does not like the way rank_t is setup and I am not sure why" Please provide your "fixed" [mre] code and compiler errors.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a common problem, a quick search turns up this, that seems to be doing what you want:
http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/219420/

If you are practicing CPP, the best way of doing things would be to learn to use CPP's library of STL common data structures and algorithms. They are powerful tools optimized for performance. Not to mention they are super common, and I would say is a sign of a 'professional' programmer.